# What will happen if I delete all user profiles, rebuild connection and start a full sync?

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync

In my sharepoint 2013 test environment, I have 20 users and I found some of their properties are not sync with AD. I cannot find the resolution and I would like to try delete all user profiles, delete existing connection and rebuild, and start a full sync.

My sharepoint site also have My Site Host deployed. During above operation I will not change any AD users or groups. Maybe I know whether all the users' my site (their blog, following, etc) will be reserved? Beside, what other impact I should consider before perform the actions?

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: Have you tried sync'ing the user profiles with PowerShell first? Does Set-SPUser –Identity ‘<domain>\<username> –SyncFromAD –Web http://<name of web app>  get the profiles to sync?

Comment: In Manage user profile page I can see "domain\mark" listed in active profiles. Then I run above command with domain\mark it return "Sp-User: you must specify a valid user object or user identity"

Comment: Set-SPUser will only update the user property for the web (SPSite and all root webs) but not the user profile sync. If the problem is a bad sync the set-spuser would not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the profiles you will loose the data stored in the profiles, but not the personal sites. Rather than delete the profiles, I would begin by recreating the connection. Then run a full import and troubleshoot the import with the MIISClient.

If that does not work you can then try more drastic approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I think you have answered my question. Just one more follow up question. I modify the email field on AD for a user. But the sync never connection never aware the update. MIIclient report 0 for deltasync. What should I check?

Comment: If you edited the field in AD and the UPS is not picking up the change I would ensure that you granted Replicating Directory Changes to the import account correctly. (If this is an answer can you mark it so? :))